# PLS-00341: declaration of cursor 'PROJECT_PARAMS_CSR' is incomplete or malformed

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle12c

This is perfectly working in oracle 12.2. problem is coming in 11g R2.

I have below cursor.

```
CURSOR project_params_csr
    IS
      SELECT project_id,
             pop.organization_id,
             DECODE(mp.primary_cost_method, 1, NULL, 2, g_project_param_cst_group_id) AS costing_group_id,
             wp.default_discrete_class AS wip_acct_class_code,
             DECODE(pop.transfer_ipv, 'Y', pop.ipv_expenditure_type, NULL) AS ipv_expenditure_type,
             DECODE(pop.transfer_erv, 'Y', pop.erv_expenditure_type, NULL) AS erv_expenditure_type,
             DECODE(pop.transfer_freight, 'Y', pop.freight_expenditure_type, NULL) AS freight_expenditure_type,
             DECODE(pop.transfer_tax, 'Y', pop.tax_expenditure_type, NULL) AS tax_expenditure_type,
             DECODE(pop.transfer_misc, 'Y', pop.misc_expenditure_type, NULL) AS misc_expenditure_type
      FROM pa_projects_all pp,
           pjm_org_parameters pop,
           mtl_parameters mp,
           wip_parameters wp
      WHERE pp.pm_product_code = 'PJM'
        AND mp.organization_id = pop.organization_id
        AND wp.organization_id = pop.organization_id
        AND pop.organization_id IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(g_project_param_org_ids_tbl))
        AND pp.name LIKE p_prefix || '%';
```

in this cursor below is variable which is in declare section.

```
p_prefix          IN         VARCHAR2,
```

`g_project_param_org_ids_tbl` is the table defined in package spec and initialized in body.

```
TYPE number_tbl_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER;    
  g_project_param_org_ids_tbl  number_tbl_type;
  g_project_param_org_ids_tbl := number_tbl_type(602, 603);
```

`g_project_param_cst_group_id` is also global variable, defined in package specification.

```
  g_project_param_cst_group_id NUMBER := 1020;
```

what could be the issue? How can I modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with the below one

```
AND pop.organization_id IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(g_project_param_org_ids_tbl))
```

Prior to Oracle 12c, TABLE() function can be applied only over collections that are defined in schema. (As SQL Type)

So, Oracle 11g does not understand `g_project_param_org_ids_tbl` in this context. You should probably create it as SQL Type first

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE number_tbl_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER; 
/
```